# Host a third party application on windows azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure

Hi I have a website made it in ASP.NET, I don't have the code to create the web role instance, but I have already hosted my application in a virtual machine. Does anybodoy knows if can I host this application in a windows azure instance? Thanks.

Comment: If you can run it in IIS you should be able to use it as a web role, you don't need the source code.  However you can also use VM roles in azure where you just upload a MS VM image file.

Comment: I know how to create a web role and link a asp.net or asp.net mvc VS project, but no idea of how to link it with an existing hosted app. Have you got any useful doc about it? I've been looking for in the web, but I couldnt find a similar example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "link with hosted app", you do need to get hold of the compiled application, i.e. the dlls and view/pages etc.  If you have a VM with the app running on you can deploy it directly using a VM role http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/compute/

Comment: Thanks Ben! What I tried to say with "link with hosted app" is simply instead of creating a new Web Role based on an existing Web Project under my solution, to create it based on the virtual directory where I already have my application hosted. Does make sense? I'd prefer to create a web role, but if I can't will use the VM approach, thanks!

Comment: I think that this is what I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432956.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your ASP.NET project is a web site and not a web app, its a little complicated. If its a web app, converting it into a Web Role is simply a matter of adding a cloud service project to the solution and then right-click on the "roles" branch in that project and "add existing web role in solution" option. You can then select your ASP.NET web app and *poof* its a web role. All that remains is to add any customizations you want (not required) to allow the web app to properly take advantage of the Windows Azure environment.

If its a web site, you'll first need to convert it into a web app. This really isn't any different then converting it to a web role. Which is just a matter of creating a new empty project and copying your old project's content files into the new project.

Comment: Right I have a web site, I just find this link that should let me configure the Azure Service Definition file using a virtual directory on my local IIS7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432956.aspx

Comment: I´ll make some proofs and try to verify if this is what I´m looking for, thanks